# TypeScript dotenv typed environment variables with nodemon throws error TS2322

Tags: typescript, nodemon, dotenv, ts-node

I have a TypeScript project with a script that looks like this:

```js
class MyClass {
    constructor(a?: number) { /* ... */ }
}

const x = new MyClass(process.env.MY_VARIABLE);
```

To enabled auto-completion and type-support for my environment variables, I created an `env.d.ts` file which looks like this:

```js
declare global {
    namespace NodeJS {
        interface ProcessEnv {
            MY_VARIABLE: number;
        }
    }
}

export {};
```

When I run the script using the following command, everything works fine:

```bash
tsc -p . && node -r dotenv/config dist/main.js
```

Now I'd like to run the same script using nodemon, so that it automatically restarts when changes are made. This is the command I tried:

```bash
nodemon -r dotenv/config src/main.ts
```

When executing the command, the following error occurrs:

```
src/main.ts:12:3 - error TS2322: Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.
  Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
```

Is there a way to fix this problem?

I tried adding this line to my `main.ts`:

```js
import 'dotenv/config';
```

and also tried to run the script using

```bash
ts-node src/main.ts
```

but the error still occurred.

Edit: I know that env variables normally only accept string values. I saw [this tutorial](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-process-env-type) where it also seems to work with numbers. Is there anything I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

`process.env` is a `Record<string, string>`, it can't have `number` values.

Type your `MY_VARIABLE:` as `string` and use `new MyClass(+(process.env.MY_VARIABLE ?? 0));` (ore `new MyClass(Number(process.env.MY_VARIABLE ?? 0));`) (or `constructor(a?: string)` )